# electron - drag & drop images into a div, upload it and use it

Tags: javascript, html, image, electron, drag-and-drop

I just begun to create an VJing app with Electron,
and I would like to create a div where i can drop images to use it.

I explain what I would like to : when the image is dragged and dropped into the div, then the image append in the div like a preview and I can use it like a selector (but that will be for later, it's not the real problem here)

In fact, I can't drop the image because there is a security : a message says : "Refused to load the image '' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive : "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback." and I don't know how to fix it or to find another solution to bypass...
It's important for the app, that I can save/load the images in the app to manipulate it later (change position, size, etc...) so I have to get the image's source or the path, I don't know

Can someone has a idea ? Thank you so much

I managed to make the div draggable, but I can't drop the image (gif, png, jpg) without a error message...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electron - Refused to load the image because it violates the following Content Security Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70861132/383904)

Comment: Isn't the actual full error message (like i.e: `...cy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`) helpful in resolving the issue?

Comment: like video-jockey-ing. this answer isn't working

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes it is, but did you have a solution otherwise ?

Comment: Is this one helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/32166870/383904